# Why use TAG in most of the Android logging code

Tags: android

I can see this is common practice among Android developers.

```
public final class TasksSample extends ListActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "TasksSample";
    private void method() {
        Log.i(TAG, "message");
    }
}
```

Will it be easier, if I do it this way? I need not to declare TAG for every new class.

```
public final class TasksSample extends ListActivity {
    private void method() {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "message");
    }
}
```

Comment: For me 1st version is better because it is: faster to write, easer to read (logs are  often quite long) and same pastern works also in static methods.

Comment: Since its going to be a constant value, define it as a static final at the beginning itself. That's pretty much standard in Java, nothing specific to Android.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than writing `getClass().getName()` at each place where a log is placed in a particular activity, it is always preferred to have a `TAG` that would represent the name of the activity class.

`Why use TAG?`

When you are running your application there might be more than one Activity class in it. To distinguish which activity class has logged the information in `logcat` we use a `TAG` which of course represents the name of the class.

And the proper way (I am not saying what you have written is wrong) of writing the TAG is:

```
private static final String TAG = TasksSample.class.getSimpleName(); // and not "TasksSample"
```

Comment: I use `private static final String TAG = Classes.tag(new Object(){});` with Classes.tag doing `return obj.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName()`.  This makes it less readable, but boilerplate-compatible.

Comment: It is also useful if you are want to refactor the class name.

Answer (score 6):

Every previous answer is right, but I just wanna add a little comment.

```
private static final String TAG = TasksSample.class.getSimpleName();
```

or

```
private static final String TAG = "TasksSample"
```

The latter is used when you use `proguard`. As you know, `proguard` obfuscates class names and it affects logs too.

Comment: Good info, I didn't know that, Can you provide a link or documentation which proves this.

Answer (score 1):

calling a function every time has it's toll and `getClass().getName()` is calling 2 functions every time you log something into the system (an already long process).

Therefor, it's better to save the tag is a `final static String` instead of calling the same function over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a common practice, and is supported by Google for logging & debugging. If you use `getClass().getName()` then you have to call `getClass().getName()` every time, so its a better approach use TAG.

Actually `getClass().getName()` returns the class name, where TAG represents easy understandable name/identification of your class.

Comment: as per Arun George `private static final String TAG = getClass().getName();` **is not possible** because you `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object`

Comment: thanks for pointing out that error. I have corrected my post.